# invoked storyboard is coming behind all opened window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

In a cocoa application i have invoked one storyboard on certain events like button click using :

```
NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SendStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 
NSWindowController *myController = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"SendIdentifier"]; 
[myController showWindow:nil];
```

this code is capable of invoking storyboard but i didn't understand why it is coming behind other windows which are already opened in finder.
please help me to resolve the problem. I only want it to be on the top of every window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
[super windowDidLoad];
NSRunningApplication* app = [NSRunningApplication
                             runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: pID];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];}
```

OR Use the below code:

```
NSArray* apps = [NSRunningApplication
                 runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"Your App BundleID"];
[(NSRunningApplication*)[apps objectAtIndex:0]
 activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];

[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps : YES];
```

Comment: it worked fine but once when i close the storyboard, and again try to invoke  it on the same event, storyboard doesn't get visible even after the full execution of program without any exception. Can you tell the reason why its happening like that and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Have you checked it with breakpoint..? That code is executing in second time?

Comment: yeah, once i tried with breakpoint and i tried it without breakpoints also.