# xib is not visible when try to call from app delegate of the application

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I am building a cocoa application where required to **invoke xib**. I tried with several codes but seems making mistake somewhere due to the reason the xib comes behind every window. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem and @jigs helped me with a good solution.My problem was with storyboard but ii will work for xibs also. Try this, it might be helpful to you also.
[tested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006508/invoked-storyboard-is-coming-behind-all-opened-window)